# jquery.d.ts errors when added to projects

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, typescript

1. I created a new TypeScript project.
2. Created a folder called types
3. Downloaded jquery.d.ts from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/jquery and placed it in the folder.

If I create a new TypeScript file and drag jquery.d.ts onto the document, such that the only thing at the top of the page is.

```
/// <reference path="types/jquery.d.ts" />
```

I get 101 Errors. Starting from the top of jquery.d.ts - VS has a problem with boolean in the async?: boolean; line.

```
interface JQueryAjaxSettings {
accepts?: any;
async?: boolean;
```

What am I doing wrong here, I'm assuming that jquery.d.ts has some form of dependency, but I don't know where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely cause of this error is that you are running an older version of the TypeScript compiler.

In TypeScript 0.9 the language specification was updated from `bool` to `boolean`. This means `boolean` will only compiler in 0.9+. If you have a 0.8 compiler, it won't understand what a `boolean` is.

You can either upgrade to the latest compiler, or check the version history on GitHub for jQuery.d.ts to find an old version with `bool` rather than `boolean`.

Comment: That's exactly what it was. I'd installed quite some time ago and decided to get back into it.

Answer (score 0):

**Couple of things to check**

- **Update** your typings module
- Similar modules trying to do the same thing like **core-js** and
  **es6-shim**
- There may be other files in your root directory having typings
  installed, Check for them and remove. Check where the error is
  pointing, your clue is there.

  Have all your typing in the **typings** folder and configure it in
  your **package.json** . So when you install your project dependencies
  through **npm install** all your **typings** too get installed

```js
"scripts":{
     "postinstall": "typings install"
}
```